# How to scroll UIPage view controller Automatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

In My App. I want to design the tutorial screen and I am using the page View Controller. I want my page view controller scroll automatically and page control also update.

Help Me.

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    NSUInteger index=((PageContantViewController *)viewController).pageIndex;
    if(index==NSNotFound){
        return nil;
    }
    index++;
    if(index==[self.pageTitles  count]){
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    NSUInteger index= ((PageContantViewController *)viewController).pageIndex;
    if(index==0 || index==NSNotFound){
        return nil;
    }
    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (PageContantViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
    if([self.pageTitles count]==0 || index>=[self.pageTitles count]){
        return  nil;
    }
    PageContantViewController *contantVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pageContantViewController"];
    contantVC.titleText= _pageTitles[index];
    contantVC.imageFile= _pageImages[index];
    contantVC.pageIndex= index;

    return contantVC;
}

-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController{
    return [_pageTitles count];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you working with storyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Use this code it will be help you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    currentIndex = 0;
    self.delegate = self;
    self.dataSource = self
    // setup time interval here

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(loadNextController)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

    // set main controller
    NSArray *mainViewControllers = @[[self  viewControllerAtIndex:self.index]];

    [self setViewControllers: startingViewControllers
                   direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated: YES
                  completion: nil];
}
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
    return currentIndex;
}

- (void)loadNextController {

    PageContentViewController *nextViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentIndex++];
    if (nextViewController == nil) {

        currentIndex = 0;
        nextViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:currentIndex];
    }

    [self setViewControllers:@[nextViewController]
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:YES
                  completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank u Sir .. It's Working

Comment: Thanks its working but for me i did ++currentIndex in loadNextController

Comment: Its Working for me ++currentIndex in loadNextController method

Answer (score -1):

if PageViewController created in storyboard:

Set the transition style as scroll in left menu.

[image]

if PageViewController created programatically:

-`self.pageViewController.transitionStyle =UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll`